# RecyclerView won't load data retrieved from Firestore into ItemView

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

So, basically what I am trying to do is to show a bunch of Post type objects on my Android app's feed (HomeFragment). The posts are being successfully retrieved from Firestore (I did check the debugger) but somehow, not all of them get loaded in the recyclerView. The itemViewHolder is only loaded with how I defined it as an XML, fields filled with lore Ipsum.

This would be my code:

HomeFragment:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter;
    private boolean isLoading = false;
    private ArrayList<String> rowsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    public static ArrayList<Post> appliedToList = new ArrayList<>();
    private User currentUser = new User();
    private View root;
    private TextView userState;

    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null ? FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid() : null;


    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        setState();
        appliedToPostsRetrieverFromHomePage(getContext());
        checkForPostFragment();
        recyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        initAdapter();
        initScrollListener();

        return root;
    }

    private void initAdapter() {
        recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), 2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
    }

    private void initScrollListener() {
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
                if (!isLoading) {
                    if (linearLayoutManager != null && linearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == rowsArrayList.size() - 1) {
                        //bottom of list!
                        loadMore();
                        isLoading = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void loadMore() {
        rowsArrayList.add(null);
        recyclerViewAdapter.notifyItemInserted(rowsArrayList.size() - 1);

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                rowsArrayList.remove(rowsArrayList.size() - 1);
                int scrollPosition = rowsArrayList.size();
                recyclerViewAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(scrollPosition);
                int currentSize = scrollPosition;
                int nextLimit = currentSize + 10;
                while (currentSize - 1 < nextLimit) {
                    rowsArrayList.add("Item " + currentSize);
                    currentSize++;
                }
                recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                isLoading = false;
            }
        }, 2000);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachFragment(@NonNull Fragment fragment) {
        super.onAttachFragment(fragment);
    }
```

RecyclerViewAdapter:

All view types represent kind of the same layout, the only difference between them is what is wrote on a certain button. Remember, some of the posts are successfully loaded!

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private final int VIEW_TYPE_APPLY = 0;
    private final int VIEW_TYPE_MORE = 1;
    private final int VIEW_TYPE_BEGIN = 2;
    private final int VIEW_TYPE_PENDING = 3;
    private final int VIEW_TYPE_END = 4;
    private final int VIEW_TYPE_ON_GOING = 5;
    private final int VIEW_TYPE_LOADING = 6;
    private ArrayList<Post> list = new ArrayList();
    private static final String TAG = RecyclerViewAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    private Context context;
    private User currentUser;
    private int recyclerType;
    static ArrayList<User> applicantsList = new ArrayList<>();

    private String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null ? FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid() : null;
    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, int recyclerType) {
        this.context = context;
        this.recyclerType = recyclerType;
        if (recyclerType == 0) {
            myPostsRetriever(context);
        } else if (recyclerType == 1) {
            appliedToPostsRetriever(context);
        } else if (recyclerType == 2) {
            homePostsRetriever(context);
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_APPLY) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_row_apply, parent, false);
            return new ItemViewHolder(view);
        } else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_MORE) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_row_more, parent, false);
            return new LoadingViewHolder(view);
        } else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_BEGIN) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_row_begin, parent, false);
            return new LoadingViewHolder(view);
        } else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_PENDING) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_row_pending, parent, false);
            return new LoadingViewHolder(view);
        } else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_END) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_row_end, parent, false);
            return new LoadingViewHolder(view);
        } else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_ON_GOING) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_row_on_going, parent, false);
            return new LoadingViewHolder(view);
        } else {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_loading, parent, false);
            return new LoadingViewHolder(view);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        if (viewHolder instanceof ItemViewHolder) {
            populateItemRows((ItemViewHolder) viewHolder, position);
        } else if (viewHolder instanceof LoadingViewHolder) {
            showLoadingView((LoadingViewHolder) viewHolder, position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list == null ? 0 : list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (list.get(position) != null) {
            if (!list.get(position).getOwner().equals(userId) &&
                    !checkIfAlreadyAppliedToPost(position) &&
                    list.get(position).getMinNeededPersons() >= list.get(position).getApplicants()) {
                return VIEW_TYPE_APPLY;
            } else if (recyclerType == 1) {
                return VIEW_TYPE_MORE;
            } else if (list.get(position).getOwner().equals(userId) && timeCheck(list.get(position))) {
                return VIEW_TYPE_BEGIN;
            } else if (list.get(position).getOwner().equals(userId) && checkIfStarted(position)
                    || !list.get(position).getOwner().equals(userId) && checkIfAlreadyAppliedToPost(position) && !checkIfStarted(position)) {
                return VIEW_TYPE_PENDING;
            } else if (list.get(position).getOwner().equals(userId) && checkIfStarted(position)) {
                return VIEW_TYPE_END;
            } else if (!list.get(position).getOwner().equals(userId) && checkIfStarted(position)){
                return VIEW_TYPE_ON_GOING;
            }else if (list.get(position).getOwner().equals(userId))
                return VIEW_TYPE_MORE;
        }
        return VIEW_TYPE_LOADING;
    }

    private class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView title;
        TextView description;
        TextView location;
        TextView minNeededPersons;
        TextView maxNeededPersons;
        TextView reward;
        TextView time;
        CheckBox physical;
        Button button;

        ItemViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.postTitle);
            description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.postDescription);
            location = itemView.findViewById(R.id.postLocationText);
            time = itemView.findViewById((R.id.postDateAndTime));
            minNeededPersons = itemView.findViewById(R.id.people);
            maxNeededPersons = itemView.findViewById(R.id.people);
            reward = itemView.findViewById(R.id.reward);
            physical = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
            button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.applyButton);
        }
    }

    private class LoadingViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ProgressBar progressBar;

        LoadingViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            progressBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        }
    }

    private void showLoadingView(LoadingViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    }

    private void populateItemRows(ItemViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

        Post item = list.get(position);
        viewHolder.title.setText(item.getTheTitle());
        viewHolder.description.setText(item.getDescription());
        viewHolder.location.setText(item.getLocation());
        viewHolder.location.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent showLocation = new Intent(context, MapsActivity.class);
                context.startActivity(showLocation);
            }
        });
        viewHolder.minNeededPersons.setText(String.valueOf(item.getMinNeededPersons()));
        viewHolder.maxNeededPersons.setText(String.valueOf(item.getMaxPersonsNeeded()));
        viewHolder.reward.setText(String.valueOf(item.getReward()));
        viewHolder.physical.setChecked(item.isPhysical());
        Date timeAndDate = item.getTime().toDate();
        viewHolder.time.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm   dd.MM.yyyy").format(timeAndDate));

        viewHolder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (viewHolder.button.getText().equals(context.getResources().getString(R.string.apply))) {
                    onApplyTapped(position);
                    viewHolder.button.setText(R.string.pending);
                    viewHolder.button.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F2CF59"));
                    viewHolder.button.setClickable(false);
                } else if (viewHolder.button.getText().equals(context.getResources().getString(R.string.begin_job))) {
                    onBeginTapped(position);
                    viewHolder.button.setText(R.string.end_job);
                    viewHolder.button.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F8CA9D"));
                } else if (viewHolder.button.getText().equals(context.getResources().getString(R.string.end_job))) {
                    onEndTapped(position);
                    viewHolder.button.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FB8E7E"));
                    viewHolder.button.setClickable(false);
                    viewHolder.button.setText(R.string.finished);
                }
            }
        });

        viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.seePostButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{ not relevant }


    private void homePostsRetriever(Context context) {

        FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        rootRef.collectionGroup("posts").limit(10).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots) {
                for (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : documentSnapshots.getDocuments()) {
                    Post post = new Post();
                    post.setAvailability(documentSnapshot.getBoolean("available"));
                    post.setTitle(documentSnapshot.getString("title"));
                    post.setDescription(documentSnapshot.getString("description"));
                    post.setLocation(documentSnapshot.getString("location"));
                    post.setApplicants(documentSnapshot.getLong("applicants").intValue());
                    post.setOwner(documentSnapshot.getString("owner"));
                    post.setMinNeededPersons(documentSnapshot.getLong("minNrOfPeople").intValue());
                    post.setMaxPersonsNeeded(documentSnapshot.getLong("maxNrOfPeople").intValue());
                    post.setReward(Objects.requireNonNull(documentSnapshot.getLong("reward")).floatValue());
                    post.setPhysical(documentSnapshot.getBoolean("physicalExcertion"));
                    post.setTime(documentSnapshot.getTimestamp("time"));
                    post.setId(documentSnapshot.getId());
                    post.setStarted(documentSnapshot.getBoolean("started"));

                    list.add(post);
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "No document found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**I don't think you are calling bind methods correctly, try:**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

    if (viewHolder instanceof ItemViewHolder) {

        ItemViewHolder holder = (ItemViewHolder)viewHolder;
        holder.populateItemRows(holder, position);

    } else if (viewHolder instanceof LoadingViewHolder) {

        LoadingViewHolder holder = (LoadingViewHolder)viewHolder;
        holder.showLoadingView(holder , position);
    }
}
```

**Also this method:**

```
private void populateItemRows(ItemViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
.....
....
....
}
```

**Is not found in your `ItemViewHolder` class**

Comment: Sorry mate, I tried your variant but I get exact same result. Plus, I have 3 other recyclerViews which I use in the app just the way I posted here and they are working just fine.

Comment: I found out what was wrong. My onCreateOnViewHolder was only returning LoadingViewHolder.. this is what happens when you copy paste your own code not paying attention. Thx anyway